# On loading screen if orientation change then app crashes

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am facing some issue in login screen of my app, My app supports both orientation Portrait as well as landscape, in every condition it works good but when I click on Sign in button and on loading screen I change the orientation then app crashes...
I don't know where is the problem
here is error

```
  12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:406)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:308)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:323)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:306)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-22 14:29:51.559 W/Xamarin.Insights(11215):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 14:29:51.656 D/dalvikvm(11215): GC_CONCURRENT freed 536K, 41% free 4454K/7484K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 52ms
An unhandled exception occured.

12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00062] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:554 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at Android.App.Dialog.Dismiss () [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Dialog.cs:572 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at AndroidHUD.AndHUD+<DismissCurrent>c__AnonStorey4.<>m__0 () [0x0001c] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at AndroidHUD.AndHUD+<DismissCurrent>c__AnonStorey4.<>m__1 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<Send>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:32 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71 
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:2491c231-85ea-488a-93d6-5c9d0adcdbd9 (intptr,intptr)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:406)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:308)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:323)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:306)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 14:29:53.584 E/mono-rt (11215): 
12-22 14:29:53.622 W/Mono    (11215): The request to load the assembly System.Core v4.0.0.0 was remapped to v2.0.5.0
12-22 14:29:53.640 D/Mono    (11215): Unloading image System.Core.dll [0x728112e8].
12-22 14:29:53.642 D/Mono    (11215): Image addref System.Core[0x7435b280] -> System.Core.dll[0x6f1ab1f0]: 8
12-22 14:29:53.650 W/Mono    (11215): The request to load the assembly System.Core v4.0.0.0 was remapped to v2.0.5.0
12-22 14:29:53.654 D/Mono    (11215): Unloading image System.Core.dll [0x727f41e0].
12-22 14:29:53.656 D/Mono    (11215): Image addref System.Core[0x7435b280] -> System.Core.dll[0x6f1ab1f0]: 9
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
```

Thank you

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: is Landscape layout required in your app? If no then add orientation tag to activity tag of your manifest

Comment: @SumitPathak ..Did u try my solution below...If you getting any problem than let me know

Comment: @Vikas Yes it is mandatory in our app landscape mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these code in the your `Manifest.xml` file (in your activity class) then the data will not change in the both modes (landscape or portrait).

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode
```

OR USE SIMPLY THESE

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Comment: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` works fine for me.

Comment: @SumitPathak ... Are you getting the same problem or another one??

Comment: @Ravinra Actually my problem is not resolve by this, I resolve it by another way but you are confident on this code line then I accept it...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
```

Means your `Progress dialog` not dismissed completly. So you need to check whether its `null` or not and showing or not. Also put it with `try....catch` statement.

```
try {
    if ((myDialog!= null) && myDialog.isShowing()) {
        myDialog.dismiss();
    }
} catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Handle or log or ignore
} catch (final Exception e) {
    // Handle or log or ignore
} finally {
    myDialog = null;
}
```